# how to get the result (html) of thymeleaf resolver?

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I want to resolve an html with thymeleaf and then have the result and do some other process of my own on it. How can I do that?

It's like this: In my controller I add attributes to my model and thymeleaf resolves the html file based on those attributes like the following code

```html
<span th:text="${foo.name}"></span>
```

Then the result will be like this and is sent as the response for the user

```html
<span>Sample Name</span>
```

Well I want the result before it is sent for the user to do more manual edit on it for example.

Comment: Like? Can you be more specific on what kind of processing?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on what you are trying to do? Thanks!

Comment: I hope I made it clear now, please tell me if you needed more info

Comment: What kind of manual editing are you trying to do? What's the end result you are looking for?

Comment: I just want to know if I can access that html,

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you want to do manual edit on name.
Create method inside you Class that created foo object.
For example

```
public class Foo {
    private String name;


    public String getModifyName(){
       // Implement here what you want to do.

       // For example
       return "Mr. " + name;
    }
}
```

Then use the in html like `<span th:text="${foo.modifyName}">  </span>`